# Bootstrap CSS space between buttons in navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make space between buttons in navbar? I usually do that with `&nbsp;`but it doesn't work now. Here's an JSfiddle of how it looks:

http://jsfiddle.net/W6hEa/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W6hEa/1/ works for me, but is probably not what you want

Comment: Personally I think the navbar links look nicer than putting buttons in there, and you can still use the icons if you wish. Otherwise I agree with the margin-left or right. http://jsfiddle.net/W6hEa/3/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you may try `margin-left`

here is the code

```
.btn{
margin-left:10px;
}
```

here is the example:: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/W6hEa/2/)**

Answer (score 8):

Copy & paste this to your `style.css` and assign it as class attribute:

```
.btn-margin-left {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.btn-margin-right {
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

**Usage**

```
<a href="URL" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-margin-left">Link</a>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-margin-left">Button</button>
```

Comment: Prefer this method as it doesn't manipulate the default BS styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can define spacing inside the class in bootstrap 4.0x.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

So for example

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default ml-2>Button</button>
```