# How to fix bootstrap navbar button spacing?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I know this is a dumb question I should know how to solve, but I don't do front-end that much.

So, I'm making a cool navbar with bootstrap, but when I try to add more than one button, the button spacing gets weird.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

```
     <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #333;">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <img src="/static/img/AdiAvi.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
      AdiAvi
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a  class="nav-link active"   class="nav-link"  href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a  class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        
        <button type="button" id="loginButton" class="ml-2 btn btn-danger navbar-btn">
          Login
      </button>
        
        
        <button type="button" id="registerTrigger" class="ml-2 btn btn-primary navbar-btn">
            Register
        </button>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Also the buttons I am looking at are the login and register buttons.

I am using BootStrap 5

Here is an example image of what happens when I run the code:

I tried using position relative to make the distance regular, but instead, what happened was that it stayed the same. [Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeY6X.png)

Comment: #Also click on the image link des to see the image

Comment: It looks like there's no default spacing. Have you tried the solutions from this post?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065062/bootstrap-css-space-between-buttons-in-navbar

Comment: Yep, i still get the same problem

Comment: How do you want it to look like exactly? With a space between the buttons?

Comment: Yeah Basicly that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bootstrap class `ml-x` (`x` select a value of choice for your spacing) to increase spacing between buttons.
For example `ml-2`:

```
<button type="button" id="registerTrigger" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn ml-2">
            Register
</button>
```

I modified your html with that (expand viewport to make it look like in your screenshot):
https://jsfiddle.net/aeo3v29w/

For more information check out this post: [Does bootstrap have builtin padding and margin classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233489/does-bootstrap-have-builtin-padding-and-margin-classes)

Comment: I tried to do that again, but it still doesn't work.
- I edited my question with what you told me.

I get the same results. It is weird, because when i click the jsfiddle that you sent me it looks fine on there, but for some reason it is still the same for me.

Comment: Please share the actual html by opening your page and pressing F12. Then copy it. Not the source code from your project

Comment: Ok! I reupdated my question.

Comment: There are no buttons in your updated html code

Comment: Rip i updated the wrong thing. I fixed it in my updated html code.

Comment: I pasted your html into a jsfiddle and the buttons have spacings: https://jsfiddle.net/c3ubfeht/ . Do you have any other styles that could overwrite the bootstrap styles?